# Android ListView is not expanding as intended

Tags: android, listview, adapter

My scenario is like this:

```
<ScrollView     
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
   android:scrollbars="vertical"        
   android:background="#ffffeb">

   <LinearLayout 
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:padding="10dp">

      // Other stuff in between here..

      <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"   
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
         android:paddingLeft="12dp"   
         android:paddingRight="12dp">

         <Button 
            android:id="@+id/insert_ad_ad_information_category_and_type_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:text="@string/insert_ad_ad_information_category_and_type_button"/>

         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/insert_ad_ad_information_parameters_frame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ffffeb"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

The problem I have is that I can't get my `ListView` to get the right height that I want.
I'll add a couple of components with my custom `BaseAdapter` class and everything there works as intended.
But when I then debug my application I can only see 1,5 out of 3 components in the list and the rest is hidden further down in the `ListView`.
But how can I make my `ListView` calculate how many components I have and get it to show all my components directly without having too scroll down?

Another thought is if I could populate any other kind of View with my `BaseAdapter`?   Because the only reason I am using `ListView` is because of the `setAdapter()` method.

Appreciate all thoughts and comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a ListView in a ScrollView. Thats where the issue is.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any recommendations of how i could solve my problem? Could i add BaseAdapter to another type of View?

Comment: Use addHeader(View) & addFooter(View)  to the ListView before you assign it its adapter (internally it wraps the header, cursor, footer into a new cursor)

Answer (score 0):

As has been said you can't use ListView inside ScrollView.
If you want your listview have different types of items and scroll those with "normal" items
you do in fact need custom adapter. You can base it on BaseAdapter if you like
Adapter has to support your item types, and inflate appropriate layouts,